# Questions about first-order formulas of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I am new in set theory. I have 4 simple questions about first-order formulas of set theory.

1. Dose $\exists x\in Y(\varphi(x))$ stand for $\exists x(x\in Y\wedge\varphi(x))$ ?
2. Dose $\forall x\in Y(\varphi(x))$ stand for $\forall x(x\in Y\rightarrow \varphi(x))$ ?
3. $\exists x\in Y(\varphi(x))\Longleftrightarrow\neg\forall x\in Y(\neg\varphi(x)) $ holds ?
4. Is $\exists y\in Z\big[\forall x\in y\big[x\subseteq U\big]\big]$ a well-formed first-order formula ?

Answer (score 0):

1. yes
2. yes.
3. holds whenever $Y\ne\emptyset$.
4. regarding $Z$ and $U$ as fixed parameters, yes, the formula is well-formed.

Comment: (4) isn't *quite* right, since "$\subseteq$" isn't a primitive symbol in the language of set theory (and this is ignoring the bounded quantifier shorthands as well).

Comment: Also, you don't need $Y$ to be nonempty in $(3)$ - it holds for all $Y$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Did you mean that I should write (4) as $\exists y\in Z\big[\forall x\in y\big[\forall v\in x\big[v\in U\big]\big]\big]$ ? Is this a well-formed formula ?

Comment: @Marvin Yes, that would be better - whether or not it's a well-formed formula depends on exactly the syntax you're using (there are many systems which are "equivalent" in an appropriate sense but allow different expressions).